# Validate data for a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005-express

I am used to using the validate object in ASP .Net to check the users input before I would execute the sp to insert the data into the DB.

How does one go about using a validate object in a win application?

I am using:

- VS C# 2008 express
- MS SQL express that comes with the above.

I search the questions by other user and most of them deal with validation on the back-end.

I would like the user to see that the inputed data is wrong if it is!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will depend heavily on the structure of your application and user interface.  A native application has a lot more leeway on that than a web site tied to a request/response model.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you question. I have a few textboxs, datagrid and an add button. I would like to verify the data typed in by the user before they can use the submit buttom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) class. This works in a similar manner to ASP.NET validators.